# redirect url to requested page after login codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue while login . when i click on a link and if i am not loggedin than it will redirect me to login page and after success login it should redirect me requested url but it redirect me to profile page.
here is my view file:

```
<!--Left cols-->
<?php error_reporting(0);?>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
<div class="reg-form">
<h2>Member's Login</h2>
<title>Login</title>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/register_step1/login">

<div class="row">
<label for="name">Email</label>
<span><i class="icon-name"></i><input type="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required id="name" name="email"/></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
<label for="pass">Your Password</label>
<span><i class="icon-pass"></i><input type="password" placeholder="*************" id="pass" required name="password"/></span>
</div>
<!--input type="hidden" name="redirurl" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" /-->
<div class="row">
Forgot Password <a href="">click here</a> / <a href="">Register</a> new user
</div>

<div class="row">
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view("home_template/rightbar");?>
```

And this is my controller :

```
public function login(){
        $this->load->model("User_model");
        $this->load->library('user_agent');

        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
            //$url = $this->input->post("redirurl");
                $data = $this->User_model->login();
                if($data){
                    foreach($data as $dta){
                        $id = $dta->id;
                        $email = $dta->email;
                    }

                    $session_array = array("id"=>$id,"email"=>$email);
                    $this->session->set_userdata("logged_by_login",$session_array);

                    redirect("profile");

                }
            }
                else{

                }


        $data["main_content"] = "login_view";
        $this->load->view("home_template/template",$data);
    }
```

Comment: try putting `exit;` after `redirect("profile");` line

Comment: Thanks @ nishant solanki you did not get my point please read it once more

Comment: what you mean by **requested page**?? Do you want to redirect the user to **last visited page**??

Comment: Yes last visited page

Comment: you can use something like `redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`... also please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167861/how-can-a-page-redirect-users-back-to-previous-page-if-they-try-to-access-the-pa

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect like this. Might be controller not get correct path,

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect(base_url('profile'));
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: why you can pass base_url('profile') inside redirect statement ? you can simply pass profile inside redirect  ex. redirect('profile','refresh');

Comment: check redirect(), base_url() / site_url() concept in cod igniter.

Comment: $this->load->helper('url');
redirect(base_url('profile)); //this line given syntax error please check

Answer (score 0):

- for page redirection we used redirect() statement in codeigniter.
  redirect() sends the user to the specified web page using a redirect
  header statement.
- redirect() statement resides in the URL helper so we need to load url helper:

  $this->load->helper('url');
- profile page redirection we write bellow statement and pass first parameter as "Profile" and second last parameter is "refresh/location".

  **redirect('profile','refresh');**
- The redirect function loads a local URI specified in the first
  parameter of the function call and built using the options specified
  in your config file.
- The second parameter allows the developer to use different HTTP
  commands to perform the redirect "location" or "refresh".
- According to the Code Igniter documentation: "Location is faster, but
  on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem." so better to use "refresh" as second parameter

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

un comment your code
" /-->

change to

```
<!input type="hidden" name="redirurl" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

and in your controler change code as shown below

```
if($data){
                foreach($data as $dta){
                    $id = $dta->id;
                    $email = $dta->email;
                }

                $session_array = array("id"=>$id,"email"=>$email);
                $this->session->set_userdata("logged_by_login",$session_array);

                redirect("profile");
                 if(!empty($this->input->post('redirurl'))){
                        redirect($this->input->post('redirurl'),'refresh'); 
                    }else{
                        redirect('profile','refresh'); 
                    }

            }
```